# Spring Social with simple OpenID

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-social

Is it possible to use Spring Social with simple OpenID providers like Wordpress, Livejournal or Steam? Seems like Spring Social can implement only OAuth2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It enables Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User.

Spring implementation is indenpendent on Open Id providers,It means spring behaves same for all OpenId providers, some of the Common OpenID providers are Yahoo!, AOL, Flickr, or MySpace....

So if Spring works same for Wordpress, Livejournal, Steam or any other open Id providers.

As most of the OpenId providers are moving to OAuth2.0 or OAuth connect implementation like google.Spring also came up with OAuth2.0 and social login implmentations.

1) [Simple example](https://github.com/sunilpulugula/SpringSecurityOpenIdLoginExample) of Open Id connect with Yahoo OpenId provider.

2) Spring security [social login example](https://github.com/sunilpulugula/SpringSecuritySocialLoginExample).

Comment: What is the difference between Spring social and OpenId? When to use which one?